# H2 Console showing mysql table which not exist

Tags: mysql, h2

I installed H2 in order to work with it on a Springboot project. I tried to setup the application to make it work with MySQL.

The version i use is the following : h2-2018-03-18. I also had to install MySQL Driver. I used mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.  I updated the h2.bat, h2w.bat and h2.sh in order to put mysql in the application path ...

In h2.bat and h2w.bat:

```
@java -cp "h2-1.4.197.jar;mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar;%H2DRIVERS%;%CLASSPATH%" org.h2.tools.Console %*
@if errorlevel 1 pause
```

In h2.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
dir=$(dirname "$0")
java -cp "$dir/h2-1.4.197.jar:mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:$H2DRIVERS:$CLASSPATH" org.h2.tools.Console "$@"
```

[image: Before Login]

After login I can list a weird list of tables... (which are not tables at all)

[image: After login]

Comment: That's the list of all (system) tables from all databases. Apparently the h2 console does not filter by database (schema)

Comment: it is what i thought ... just annoying